# Proxy settings for all outbound curl connection in PHP

Tags: php, curl, proxy

I am behind a proxy and have a bunch of PHP applications using several different libraries which rely on curl so it is almost impossible to update the code to set proxy configuration for every library on every application. Is there any way to set up a base system-wide curl configuration (i.e. proxy configuration) for any outbound connection?

PD: My OS is Ubuntu 14.04. I have configured the proxy on System Network Proxy UI and even curl in bash console but those configs don't affect curl on PHP.

Comment: Maybe the external system-level curl library has a global config file, but there's nothing in PHP for this. there's only one .ini setting for curl, and has nothing to do with proxies.

Comment: Thanks Marc, I appreciate your answer. It will become so hard to read every library documentation to find out if they have a way to set proxy configuration and maybe some of then (oldest ones) have no way so I thought it would be a frequent problem on sysadmin world but it's disappointing that there is no solution for this kind of situation nowadays. It could be as simple as: curl.proxy="user:pass@server:port" just like existing curl.cainfo on php.ini file.